# Spring Oauth Authorization Server + Client Domains & Session Cookie Issue

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I currently have a frontend server A, BFF (back end for front end server B) and server C (authorization server). I used `mkcert` in order to create valid certifications in order to test properly and I also did it to use HTTP only cookies with `secure` set to `true` and `same site` to `none`  (I had a lot of bugs regarding sessions cookies), but I still see some bugs despite of using HTTPS and cookies accordingly.

For somewhat reason, if auth server and BFF are on the same domain lets say one is on `https://zonal:8081` and the other on `https://zonal:8082` then the session cookies will be overwritten and i'll get the authorization code request not found, because server B will store the authorization request for session X, and when it's being redirected back from server C, session will be different and thus, the error.

If I put the authorization server on a different domain (
`https://authserver:8082`) than server A and server B, then it works, and it will be the same session on server B and server C, however there is still an issue. If I send requests from frontend to server B, it will be session X, if I send to authorization server, it will be session Y, and all these servers are using HTTPS and HTTP only cookie with secured and same site to none.

Is there any way to clarify this aspects? I think its very important and I don't see it documented anywhere.

Comment: "Is there any way to clarify this aspects?" Sorry @loredon, I don't think I understand what you're asking. Are you asking if there's an existing guide or example for the proper way to set this up? If so, I'd ask to please to clarify what use case requires you to make a request from frontend/UI (hosted on server A) to server C? The BFF is intended to be an intermediary, and therefore you should make your requests to server B.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I had the oauth server and the bff server on different domains so there was a clash between the cookies. Now i have put them on the same domain,they actually on sub domains. However, a problem still persists because i'm trying to scale the BFF and the Oauth Server , in this case i have 2 isntances of Oauth Server. Is there any way to store the sessions on a redis using spring authorization server? Will the classical way of calling redis for spring security like annot EnableRedisHttpSession work? But then again i think the tokens are also stored with the sessions.

Comment: You can use Spring Session with redis in Authorization Server. The tokens are actually not stored in the session, they have their own data store managed by the OAuth2AuthorizationService.